# Free shipping shopping cart rule and discount coupon

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

We need to be able to offer free shipping via shopping cart price rule to all orders above 100 dollars. We also need to be able to have a discount coupon that gives certain amount of discount on the whole order.

Now, the problem is that Magento gives free shipping even if the discount coupon reduces the order sum below the 100 dollar limit we have set. So now we give a free shipping orders below 100 dollars.

We also have to use the shopping cart price rule, because we have a shipping methods via extensions that integrate to carriers system. So we can't use the Magento's free shipping method. We also need to specify the shipping methods that can have a free shipping.

So is there any way we could get Magento to apply the discount before it calculates if the free shipping limit is reached?

Answer (score 2):

Do you require a coupon code for the free shipping or do you give it to anyone with a cart over $100? If you don't want to require a code, I would recommend this setup:

**Rule Information:**

- No Coupon Code
- Priority 0

**Conditions**:

- If all of these conditions are true (whatever country or state restrictions for free shipping)
- If any of these conditions are true:
- *Subtotal equal or greater than 100.00*
- *Subtotal is 0.00*

**Actions:**

- Everything set to 0 or no except *Free Shipping* which you set to "For Matching Items Only"

I've had free shipping rules like this setup for some time and have not encountered any issues with their total (after coupons) going below the free shipping amount and still having the free shipping apply.

-Kaylie

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two shopping cart price rules. One for the free shipping over 100$ and another for the specific coupon. You than have to set the **priority** for the rules: in your case you need to set lower priority to the coupon code in order to be processed first. Take a look at : http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them
and
 http://grafischdirect.com/blog/how-to-use-magento-shopping-cart-price-rules

Comment: The shopping cart price rule's priority does not seem to have any effect. It could work if I could set the free shipping rule to come into play if the discounted price is above 100 dollars. There is no such option and only the subtotal is found in the conditions of the rule and magento sees the subtotal as the original subtotal, not the discounted subtotal.

Comment: Priority does work for me, however, total after discount is not working. it is getting total before discount, which causes issues. so for example, if we have free shipping on orders $100 or more, and a person has $110 in cart, then uses a coupon for 20% off. They receive $22 off, which is now $88. However, they still receive free shipping, even though they shouldn't.